# Flask throwing Runtime error when ran through Gunicorn, but not through flask run

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gunicorn

I'm following along a video series for loose reference as I build the back-end of my first website using Flask. One of the videos has me writing this function verbatim to be used as a decorator:

```py
# add this as a decorator to pages that require a login
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap
```

which is used to redirect to a login if a page requires it. This works fine when testing the app using `python3 -m flask run`, but I get an internal server error with the following stack trace when I run `gunicorn main:main`

```
[2020-07-13 18:33:52 -0400] [6272] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (6272)
[2020-07-13 18:33:52 -0400] [6272] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-07-13 18:33:52 -0400] [6274] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6274
[2020-07-13 18:33:59 -0400] [6274] [ERROR] Error handling request /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/john/Developer/runjs/main.py", line 15, in wrap
    if 'logged_in' in session:
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 379, in <lambda>
    __contains__ = lambda x, i: i in x._get_current_object()
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with my function that causes it to break when run through Gunicorn. I have tried researching this, but none of the suggested fixes have seemed pertinent to my specific scenario and I am confused as to why it works locally.

Comment: Just a note - there is the `Flask-Login` extension which provides (a working) login required decorator.

Comment: If you want to figure out the problem yourself, I highly recommend this video from the last FlaskCon, which one and for all time demystifies such errors - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq8y-9UHjyk